# WP8: Any idea why OnInvoke not called in derived ScheduledTaskAgent

Tags: background, scheduled-tasks, windows-phone

Using Lumia 920, it looks like my OnInvoke is never called even in Debug mode. The Constructor of ScheduledAgent that is inherited from ScheduledTaskAgent is called. Which means that the setup in WMAppManifest.xml is correct.

```
<Tasks>
  <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="MainPage.xaml" />
  <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="PeriodicAgent" Source="ScheduledPlaybackAgent" Type="ScheduledPlaybackAgent.ScheduledAgent" />
  </ExtendedTask>
</Tasks>
```

Then I pretty much copied from sample code:

```
    private void StartPeriodicAgent()
    {
        // Obtain a reference to the period task, if one exists
        periodicTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(periodicTaskName) as PeriodicTask;

        if (periodicTask != null)
        {
            RemoveAgent(periodicTaskName);
        }

        periodicTask = new PeriodicTask(periodicTaskName);

        periodicTask.Description = "This demonstrates a periodic task.";

        try
        {
            ScheduledActionService.Add(periodicTask);
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
        {
        }
        catch (SchedulerServiceException)
        {
        }
    }
```

I purposely switch to Home screen after foreground app is started and waited as much as I can. Still no output or breakpoint from my ScheduledAgent::OnInvoke

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you have referenced the background agent's project from the application's main project. Also, when testing, you can use the `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest` method to start the agent immediately: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how often it gets called? Is there anywhere I can set frequency? How about intensive one?

Comment: A background agent is called once every 30 minutes. Note that if the battery saver is activated then the background agent won't be called. There is no way to change the frequency.

Comment: wow, it is called once per 30 minutes up to few hours on my devie. Do you mean no matter it is using ResourceIntensiveTask or PeriodicTask, it's going to take that long? Any other way that I can keep my App running at background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you defined #define DEBUG_AGENT in ScheduledAgent.cs and included the following code in OnInvoke?

```
        #if(DEBUG_AGENT)
            ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Periodic task is started again: " + task.Name);
        #endif
```

Comment: Yes I did that. It is working now but the mechanism is not useful to my use case. I had to use some other ways. Thanks a lot!